# pie plot is not displaying for less than the value 1 in jfreechart

Tags: java, plot, charts, jfreechart

I am new to Jfreechart. I am creating a 3d pie chart in jfreechart and adding this to pdf using itext api. I am able to generate 3d pie chart dynamically and the tool tip for the pie chart too. I am displaying the plot tool tip in percentage. But for the value that is less then 1, the plot is not getting generate.

Please anyone help me to sort this problem.

Edit: Here is my dataset:

```
final DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
result.setValue("Java", new Double(43.2));
result.setValue("Visual Basic", new Double(10.0));
result.setValue("C/C++", new Double(17.5));
result.setValue("PHP", new Double(32.5));
result.setValue("Perl", new Double(1.0));
result.setValue("dotnet", new Double(0.04));
result.setValue("python", new Double(1.06));
result.setValue("cobol", new Double(0.08));
```

Pie plot is not getting generated for "dotnet" and "cobol".

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I've updated your question to show the new code; please delete the comment.

Comment: What result do you expect for such small values?

Comment: I need to display the pie plots, that how many values are set to the pie dataset. Because First i am display the values that are set in the pie dataset from database and after that i am displaying the pie chart. That time values are there but the pie plots are not there. This is my problem. I have to show all the pie plots. How to do this. Please i need help.

Comment: Since you already display the values, why not use `DatasetUtilities. createConsolidatedPieDataset` to collect "others"?

Comment: I used the code like this, PieDataset newResult = DatasetUtilities.createConsolidatedPieDataset(result, "Other", 0.001);

Comment: I used the code like this, PieDataset newResult = DatasetUtilities.createConsolidatedPieDataset(result, "Other", 0.001);  That time "Other" become 0.12. And it is less then 1. so, it is not creating the pie plot in the pie chart. Could you help me how to draw the pie plot for this less value in the pie chart. Otherwise i have to hide the labelLink and the value. Please help me to sort this problem.